# How to change text dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the text to be editable when click on the edit icon. The div is already draggable. It has to be done using javascript. Can anyone help me?

HTML code

```
<ul class="drag-list">
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Not a fit</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Lack of knowledge</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Hired elsewhere</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS code

```
.drag-list>.title {font-weight:bold; color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list li a {margin-right:5px; color:#8aa2ad; padding:6px 6px;}
.drag-list li a:hover {color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list {margin: 0 auto; padding:0;}
.drag-list > li {list-style: none; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); margin: 5px 0;}
.drag-list .title {display: inline-block; padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px; vertical-align: top; max-width:50%; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
.drag-list .drag-area {display: inline-block; border-right:1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); width: 40px; height: 32px; vertical-align: top; cursor: move;}
```

.drag-area i {text-align:center; width:100%; padding-top:9px; font-size:16px; color:#ccc;}

Comment: Well, that's very helpful code you got there sir. Now, how about actual code that will do? Have you tried anything?

Comment: You need to use a textbox to hold the new data and need an event to change the innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.fa-pencil').click(function() {
console.log();
  $(this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling).attr('contentEditable', true)
});
```

```css
.drag-list>.title {font-weight:bold; color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list li a {margin-right:5px; color:#8aa2ad; padding:6px 6px;}
.drag-list li a:hover {color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list {margin: 0 auto; padding:0;}
.drag-list > li {list-style: none; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); margin: 5px 0;}
.drag-list .title {display: inline-block; padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px; vertical-align: top; max-width:50%; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
.drag-list .drag-area {display: inline-block; border-right:1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); width: 40px; height: 32px; vertical-align: top; cursor: move;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="drag-list">
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Not a fit</span>
    <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Lack of knowledge</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Hired elsewhere</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

see the snippet. when you click on pencil icon than you can edit the content of div.
clicking on pencil will set the attr contentEditable to true.

```js
$('.fa-pencil').click(function() {
  if($(this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling).attr('contentEditable') === "true"){
    $(this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling).attr('contentEditable', false);
  } else {
     $(this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling).attr('contentEditable', true);
     $(this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling).focus();
  }
});
```

```css
.drag-list>.title {font-weight:bold; color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list li a {margin-right:5px; color:#8aa2ad; padding:6px 6px;}
.drag-list li a:hover {color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list {margin: 0 auto; padding:0;}
.drag-list > li {list-style: none; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); margin: 5px 0;}
.drag-list .title {display: inline-block; padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px; vertical-align: top; max-width:50%; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
.drag-list .drag-area {display: inline-block; border-right:1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); width: 40px; height: 32px; vertical-align: top; cursor: move;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="drag-list">
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Not a fit</span>
    <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Lack of knowledge</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Hired elsewhere</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

See the updated code snippet, once you again click on pencil icon your changes will get saved.

Comment: Thank you Sumit. This code works. Can u please do one more thing.

Comment: How can the text be editable after clicking edit icon

Comment: see now. created new snippet to save the changes also

Comment: glad to help you out. :p

Comment: Can u please help me one more time. After clicking edit icon how can the edit box be highlighted?

Answer (score 3):

`contenteditable="true"` does the trick, click the text you want to edit

```css
.drag-list>.title {font-weight:bold; color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list li a {margin-right:5px; color:#8aa2ad; padding:6px 6px;}
.drag-list li a:hover {color:#4c5258;}
.drag-list {margin: 0 auto; padding:0;}
.drag-list > li {list-style: none; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); margin: 5px 0;}
.drag-list .title {display: inline-block; padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px; vertical-align: top; max-width:50%; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
.drag-list .drag-area {display: inline-block; border-right:1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196); width: 40px; height: 32px; vertical-align: top; cursor: move;}
```

```html
<ul class="drag-list">
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title" contenteditable="true">Not a fit</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title" contenteditable="true">Lack of knowledge</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span class="title" contenteditable="true">Hired elsewhere</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <li>
    <span class="drag-area"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <span id="title1" class="title">Not a fit</span>
      <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="pull-right" onclick='document.getElementById("title1").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");'><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
   </li>
```